# Flask question: redirect not behaving as expected

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm working on my first `flask` practice project and can't figure out why redirect does not work. The posts page has blog posts, and the edit page at `/post/edit/id` is supposed to update them. The form seems to work but when you save it goes to `/posts/edit/posts/edit/1` rather than just `/posts`, even though `/posts` is passed in `redirect`. Here's the main code:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from datetime import datetime


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///posts.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Blogpost(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=False, default='N/A')
    title = db.Column(db.String(30), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.String(150), nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.utcnow)


def __repr__(self):
    return str(self.id)


@app.route('/home')
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/posts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    if request.method =='POST':
        post_title = request.form['title']
        post_author = request.form['author']
        post_content = request.form['content']
        new_post = Blogpost(title=post_title, author=post_author, content=post_content)
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/posts')
    else:    
        all_posts = Blogpost.query.order_by(Blogpost.date_posted).all()
        return render_template('posts.html', posts=all_posts)

@app.route('/posts/delete/<int:id>')
def delete(id):
    post = Blogpost.query.get_or_404(id)
    db.session.delete(post)
    db.session.commit()
    return redirect('/posts')

@app.route('/posts/edit/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit(id):

    post = Blogpost.query.get_or_404(id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post.title = request.form['title']
        post.author = request.form['author']
        post.content = request.form['content']
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect('/posts')
    else:    
        return render_template('edit.html', post=post)   


@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('aboutus.html', title='About')  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And here's the html:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block content %}

<h1>Edit Post</h1>
<hr>

<form action='posts/edit/{{ post.id }}' method='POST'>
    Title: <input type='text' name='title' id='title', value={{post.title}}>  
    <hr>
    Author: <input type='text' name='author' id='author', value={{post.author}}>
    <hr>
    Post: <input type='text' name='content' id='content', value= {{post.content}} >
    <hr>
    <input type='submit' value='Save'>
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

The base html file is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% if title %}
        <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
        <title>Welcome</title>
    {% endif %}    
</head>
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
<body>
    {% block content2 %} 
    {% endblock %}   

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

redirect example:

```
from flask import url_for

@app.route('/index')
def Index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@app.route('/sample')
def Sample():
    return redirect(url_for('Index'))
```

When the user enters the "/ sample" path, it is directed to the / index path